# AWS lambda - sam build returns error when building dependencies for torch library

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

Following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/machine-learning/using-container-images-to-run-pytorch-models-in-aws-lambda/) tutorial, I am trying to employ a pytorch model. I set the Dockerfile up as intended and when I run `sam build`, everything works except for the requirements. It returns the following error message:

```
Collecting torch==1.8.1
  Downloading torch-1.8.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (804.1 MB)

Build Failed
Error: HelloWorldFunction failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .' returned a non-zero code: 137
```

Unfortunately, there is no information on what causes the error. Is this related to the size of the torch package? If so, is there any workaround?

Comment: What is the python version on your Lambda function?

Comment: It is python 3.8

Comment: I believe you need to upload the torch lib to S3 bucket first. Then, you need to refer to it in Lambda function. There is a limit for dependencies on Lambda (50MB for zipped files, 250MB for unzipped files). See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at a template provided by AWS, where they employ a PyTorch model. There, they solve the issue by the following approach in the `requirements.txt` file:

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==1.8.0+cpu
```

I am not sure, if this version is that much more leight-weighted, but it works.